# Find next number in the series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The given series is 
121,169,289,361,526...
Options are:
A)841 B)625 C)784 D)729 E)none of the above

I don't know how to solve it.
It doesn't fit for common difference method where you find the difference with the previous number and difference of the difference until you find common number.

The difference of the numbers is 48,120,72,165
Here you can actually see some common things. The 1st and 3rd number and 2nd and 4th numbers seems to have something common. But there is far less information.

Comment: It is 526......

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure it's 526 and not 529? The pattern seems to be it's the square of prime numbers above 7.

$$121 = 11^2 \quad 169 = 13^2 \quad 289 = 17^2 \quad 361 = 19^2 \quad 529 = 23^2.$$

My guess for the next term would be $841 = 29^2$ since $29$ is the next prime.

Comment: I don't know the question paper says it's 526